# jQuery success/error functions

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using a form on a page to have a user input the url of an image that will be used for various purposes. I'm write an ajax method to determine whether their supplied url is actually an image or not. So far I've done this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {

    $("#AppBackgroundImage").on('blur', function () {

        var providedImage = $(this);
        var URL = providedImage.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: providedImage.val(),
            type: "GET",
            success: function () { $("#imageThumbnail").attr("src", URL); },
            error: function () { $("#imageThumbnail").attr('src', "C:\Users\jorda_000\Desktop"); }

        });

        //$("#imageThumbnail").attr("src", URL);
    })

})
```

When I comment out the success and error functions and uncomment the bottom line of code, when I click out of the form input it will update the thumbnail (id = "imageThumbnail") with the appropriate image. If it's not an image, it will display a blank thumbnail.

Is it viable to pass in the two .attr methods I'm trying to do or will I have to handle that elsewhere? I want it to display the appropriate image if the url is an image, and display a default image if it's not (with an appropriate error message).

Comment: If the URL returns HTML rather than an image, the AJAX call will still be successful.

Comment: If the URL is of a different domain, this will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {

    $("#AppBackgroundImage").on('blur', function () {

        var providedImage = $(this);
        var URL = providedImage.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: providedImage.val(),
            type: "GET",
            error: function () { URL = "C:\Users\jorda_000\Desktop"); }
            complete: function () { $("#imageThumbnail").attr("src", URL); }
        });

    })

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you not always need a success function then? Or does the complete function handle both cases?

Comment: Ya, complete function handle both cases and is fired after succes/error

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just wanted to make sure I understood fully what's going on.